# CanBuildFrom and upper type bound parameters

Tags: scala

Here is a minimalistic example:

```scala
def map[U[_] <: Traversable[T], T](col: U[T]): U[T] 
    = col.map(identity)
```

This code does not compile.

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Traversable[T]
 required: U[T]
    = col.map(identity)
```

My understanding of the problem is the `col.map(identity)` where the compiler infers an implicit `CanBuildFrom[U[T], T, Traversable[T]]` instead of desired `CanBuildFrom[U[T], T, U[T]]`.

Is there a way to make this code working?

Comment: You may want to take a look to this: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/custom-collection-operations.html

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thank you for the article! That' helped me to move in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mechanics of builder type classes in Scala 2.12 is something like so

```
def foo[CC[x] <: Traversable[x], A, B](as: CC[A], f: A => B)(
  implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[CC[A], B, CC[B]]
): CC[B] = {
  val bf = cbf()
  as.foreach { a => bf += f(a) }
  bf.result()
}
```

or using `.to` method

```
def foo[CC[x] <: Traversable[x], A, B](as: CC[A], f: A => B)(
  implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[CC[A], B, CC[B]]
): CC[B] = {
  as.map(f).to[CC]
}
```

Corresponding Scala 2.13 code might be

```
def foo[CC[x] <: Iterable[x], A, B](as: CC[A], f: A => B)(
  implicit cbf: BuildFrom[CC[A], B, CC[B]]
): CC[B] = {
  cbf.fromSpecific(as)(as.map(f))
}
```

or using factory

```
def foo[CC[x] <: Iterable[x], A, B](as: CC[A], f: A => B)(
  implicit factory: Factory[B, CC[B]]
): CC[B] = {
  as.map(f).to(factory) // equivalent to factory.fromSpecific(as.map(f))
}
```

The meanings of three type parameters of collection builder type class are

```
             | source coll | element of target coll | target coll   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
CanBuildFrom | -From       | -Elem                  | +To           |
BuildFrom    | -From       | -A                     | +C            |
Factory      |             | -A                     | +C            |
```

Note these builder type classes are just generalised version of the following idea

```
scala> val bf = List.newBuilder[Int]
val bf: scala.collection.mutable.Builder[Int,List[Int]] = ListBuffer()

scala> bf += 1 += 4
val res0: bf.type = ListBuffer(1, 4)

scala> bf.result()
val res1: List[Int] = List(1, 4)
```

but in practice we rarely see collections constructed in such way.

Another option instead of `BuildFrom` is to use cats type classes such as [`Functor`](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/functor.html).

Comment: thanks, I quickly tested your 2.12 option and it worked! So, the key here is that I must have manually moved elements from the input collection to a builder. But I still don't get why it doesn't work if I do a simple `as.map(f)(cbf)`? Does `as.map(f)` return not a `CC[A]` but the bound `Traversable[A]`? I must be missing something important here.

Comment: @egordoe `as.map(f)` has type `Iterable[B]` in my example.

Comment: I meant the very first example in your post. The type of `as` is `CC[A]`. Question: Why is the type of `as.map(f)`  not a `CC[B]` but `Traversable[B]`?

Comment: Anyway, it seems like the original question has been answered, so I am marking the answer as an accepted one.

Comment: @egordoe Because of the upper type bound `CC[x] <: Traversable[x]` the most specific type `map` can return is `Traversable[B]`.